# Wordpress Installation in Laravel 5.5

Tags: wordpress, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I need to install Wordpress into Laravel 5.5.

Can anyone tell me either it is possible to install wordpress into Laravel directory.

I need to use blog into my Laravel Application.
Like: http://myapplication.com/blog (blog will be in Wordpress)

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,You can follow this link-https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/install-wordpress-in-domaincomblog. and https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/install-wordpress-with-laravel-in-same-domain-in-folder-blog?page=1

Answer (score 0):

You can installed Wordpress inside public folder.

Folder structure should be laravel-directory/public/blog

I hope this will work for you.